# Loading CSV data to Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having some trouble reading some csv data into a pandas data frame 
because the actual output of the code is not similar to expected output.

Raw data

```
c1  c2  c3                          c4  c5  c6
aa  bb  "\"a\\\"\"b\";;;c;d,e,f"    cc  dd  ee
```

Actual output

```
c1  c2  c3                  c4  c5  c6
aa  bb  \a\\\"\"b\";;;c;d   e   f
```

Expected output

```
c1  c2  c3                  c4  c5  c6
aa  bb  \a\\\\b\;;;c;d,e,f  cc  dd  ee
```

---

* Actual output - after loading my code

Here is the code that I use:

```
df = pd.read_csv("path",
                  sep = ',', quotechar='"')
```

I have tried the read_csv command with and without explicitly defining the delimiter but no success. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In reviewing the panda documentation for reading a csv file, I believe all you need to do is change the read call from:

```
df = pd.read_csv("path", sep = ',', quotechar='"')
```

to:

```
df = pd.read_csv("path", sep = '|', escapechar='"')
```

After trying out that change with your raw data, I did a simple "print(df.to_string(index=False))" without any formatting and here is what I got.

```
c1  c2  c3                          c4  c5  c6
      aa  bb  \a\\\\b\;;;c;d,e,f    cc  dd  ee
```

I also revised the separator to some likely unused character since it actually looked like tabs rather than commas were being used as the field separators.

I am not sure if this is more what you were looking for, but you I think you want to  explore setting the escape character parameter.

Hope that helps.

Regards.

Comment: how can I breakdown this into columns.
aa,bb,"\a\\\\b\;;;c;d,e,f",cc,dd,ee  where c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6 as header

and i want to load it like this
c1 c2 c3                  c4 c5 c5
aa bb \a\\\\b\;;;c;d,e,f  cc dd ee

Comment: already used comma as separator and escapechar = '"' but the output is still not what I expect